# Complex Analysis - Mathematics

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an open, connected set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and define $g$ by $g(z) = 1/f(z)$ if $f(z) \neq 0$. Recall that $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z \in$ $\Omega$ if $f(z) = f'(z) = f''(z) = ... = f^{(k-1)}(z) = 0 $ and $f^{(k)}(z)\neq 0$. Prove that:

(a) If $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z \in$ $\Omega$ then $g$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z$.

(b) If $g$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z \in$ $\Omega$ then $f$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z$.

For Part (a):

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an open, connected set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f(z)$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z \in$ $\Omega$

Then $f(z)=(z-a)^k \phi (z)$ where $\phi$ $(z)$ is an analytic function in $\Omega$ and $z = a$ is a zero of order $k$.

Now: $$g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$$
$$g(z) = \frac{1}{(z-a)^k \phi (z)}$$
$$g(z) = \frac{\phi_1 (z)}{(z-a)^k}$$ (where $\phi_1 (z) = \frac{1}{\phi (z)}$)

Then: $z=a$ is a pole of order $k$ of $g$.

For Part (b):

Let $g$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z \in$ $\Omega$

Then $$g(z) = \frac{h(z)}{(z-a)^k}$$ where $h(z)$ is an analytic function in $\Omega$.

Now:$$f(z) = \frac{1}{g(z)} = \frac{1}{\frac{h(z)}{(z-a)^k}} = \frac{(z-a)^k}{h(z)}$$
$$f(z) = (z-a)^k h_1(z)$$ where $h_1(z) = \frac{1}{h(z)}$ since $h(z) \neq 0 ,\forall z \in$ $\Omega$

Then: $z = a$ is a pole of order $k$ of $f$.

Can someone please check this method of my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good, but the proof have some important details left.

For example let's show (b).

Suppose that $g$ has a pole of order $k$ at $a\in\Omega.$ Then there exists an function $h$ analytic in a *neighborhood* $U$ of $a$ such that
$$ g(z)=\frac{h(z)}{(z-a)^k}$$
in such neighborhood, *and* $h(a)\neq 0.$ Since $h$ is analytic in $U,$ is in particular continuous, hence $h(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in V$ where $V$ is some neighborhood of $a$ contained in $U.$ Then
$$ f(z)=\frac{(z-a)^k}{h(z)}$$
for all $z\in V,$ and $1/h$ is analytic in $V$ since $h$ is analytic and have no zeros in $V.$ Moreover, since $h(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in V,$ then $f$ has a zero of order $k$ in $a.$

Part (a) is similar, you should try to fill the details left in your proof.